# How to use wget with IPV6

Tags: wget, ipv6

I received an IPv6 address using the following command (and output):

```
$ dig +short +answer aaaa deb.debian.org
debian.map.fastlydns.net.
2a04:4e42:65::644
```

Now, when I try to run the following command:

```
wget -6 https://2a04:4e42:65::644
```

I get the following error:

```
https://2a04:4e42:65::644: Bad port number.
```

My wget version info:

```
GNU Wget 1.21 built on linux-gnu.
```

Is this version of wget (debian 11) not compatible with IPv6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should "escape" the address, e.g. `wget -6 https://[2a04:4e42:65::644]`

You may also want to add `--no-check-certificate` because SSL certificates are issued for domain names, not IP addresses.

Lastly you may still get an error or a default web server page as most websites are set up to serve data only when the `Host:` field is properly specified.

Comment: You can also use the DNS name. `wget -6 https://deb.debian.org`. This should address both the certificate issue and the bad default page.